# MySQL IF distinct problem - why are my records not unique?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query like this :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Users.UserID,Users.UserInfo,UserType.UserTypeName, 
            IF(Users.UserID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Aproved.UserID FROM Aproved WHERE DATE(Aproved.Date)= '2020-07-12'),'İzinli',
            IF(Users.UserID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CheckInLog.UserID FROM CheckInLog WHERE DATE(CheckInLog.CheckTime)= '2020-07-12' AND CheckInLog.CheckType=1) ,'Başladı','Giriş Yapmadı') ) AS 'Status' ,
                
            IF(Users.UserID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CheckInLog.UserID FROM CheckInLog WHERE DATE(CheckInLog.CheckTime)= '2020-07-12' AND CheckInLog.CheckType=1),
           (SELECT DISTINCT CheckInLog.CheckTime FROM CheckInLog WHERE DATE(CheckInLog.CheckTime)= '2020-07-12' AND CheckInLog.UserID=Users.UserID AND CheckInLog.CheckType=1),' - ') AS 'Start' ,
            IF(Users.UserID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CheckInLog.UserID FROM CheckInLog WHERE DATE(CheckInLog.CheckTime)= '2020-07-12' AND CheckInLog.CheckType=2),
               (SELECT DISTINCT CheckInLog.CheckTime FROM CheckInLog WHERE DATE(CheckInLog.CheckTime)= '2020-07-12' AND CheckInLog.UserID=Users.UserID AND CheckInLog.CheckType=2),' - ') AS 'End' 
            FROM Users 
            JOIN UserType ON Users.UserType=UserType.UserTypeID 
                
            Where Users.UserType != 1 and Users.UserType != 2
```

This give me data like:

[image]

But I want data to be like

[image]

My check-in log table is like:

[image]

CheckType =1 -> Start
CheckType =2 -> End

Please help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: what other fields are in 'Users' and 'UserType' table?
btw that 'UserType' as table and as field name is giving me antsy feeling haha

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Users should be duplicated in the `users` table, so it is not clear what is going on.  However, you can simplify your query considerably:

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.UserInfo, ut.UserTypeName, 
       (CASE WHEN s.UserID IN (SELECT a.UserID FROM Aproved a WHERE DATE(Aproved.Date)= '2020-07-12')
             THEN 'İzinli'
             WHEN u.UserID IN (SELECT cil.UserID FROM CheckInLog cil WHERE DATE(cil.CheckTime)= '2020-07-12' AND cil.CheckType = 1)
             THEN 'Başladı'
             ELSE 'Giriş Yapmadı'
        END) AS Status,            
       (CASE WHEN u.UserID IN (SELECT cil.UserID FROM CheckInLog cil WHERE DATE(cil.CheckTime) = '2020-07-12' AND cil.CheckType = 1),
             THEN (SELECT cil.CheckTime FROM CheckInLog cil WHERE DATE(cil.CheckTime) = '2020-07-12' AND cil.UserID = u.UserID AND cil.CheckType = 1),
             ELSE ' - '
        END) AS Start ,
       (CASE WHEN u.UserID IN (SELECT cil.UserID FROM CheckInLog cil WHERE DATE(c.cil) = '2020-07-12' AND cil.CheckType = 2)
             THEN (SELECT cil.CheckTime FROM CheckInLog cil WHERE DATE(cil.CheckTime) = '2020-07-12' AND cil.UserID = u.UserID AND cil.CheckType = 2),
             ELSE ' - '
        END) AS `End` 
FROM Users u JOIN
     UserType ut 
     ON u.UserType = ut.UserTypeID 
WHERE u.UserType NOT IN (1, 2);
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your particular problem.  But note the following:

- `NOT IN` is simpler than multiple comparisons.
- Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants, not column names.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not appropriate for an `IN` subquery.
- `CASE` is the standard form for conditional logic in SQL and is more powerful because it allows multiple clauses.